# Getting sum of duplicated date entries from last month, week, day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns: `id`, `updated_at`, `click_sum`.

Many rows have the exact same `updated_at` value which makes it hard to simply retrieve the data, `order by updated_at` and display the sums in a chart.
Since there are multiple sums for the same dates which screws the chart.

What I try to achieve is to get the following output:

```
 update_at | click_sum
-----------+-----------
   date1   |    100
   date2   |     3
   date3   |    235
   date4   |    231
```

Optionally only those dates which are form the last month, week or day `AND` not simply the dates which are `NOW() - 1` month.

The current query I build is very large and doesn't work that well.
It groups by dates (no duplicated dates appear) and `SUM()`s the clicks correctly but defining from when (last month, week, day) the dates are doesn't seem to work properly.

Query: (`$interval` stands for `MONTH` or `DAY` or `SECOND` or `WEEK`)

```
SELECT d.updated_at, SUM(d.clicks_sum) AS click_sum
FROM aggregated_clicks d
JOIN 
(
     SELECT c.id, MAX(StartOfChains.updated_at) AS ChainStartTime
     FROM aggregated_clicks c
     JOIN 
     (
         SELECT DISTINCT a.updated_at
         FROM aggregated_clicks a
         LEFT JOIN aggregated_clicks b ON (b.updated_at >= a.updated_at - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND b.updated_at < a.updated_at)
         WHERE b.updated_at IS NULL
      ) StartOfChains  ON c.updated_at >= StartOfChains.updated_at
     GROUP BY c.id
) GroupingQuery
ON d.id = GroupingQuery.id
WHERE GroupingQuery.ChainStartTime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 $interval)
GROUP BY GroupingQuery.ChainStartTime
ORDER BY GroupingQuery.ChainStartTime ASC
```

Comment: I don't understand what your desired result is.  Do you want one row per `id`?  One row per `updated_at`?  And together with that, you want the sum of something?

Comment: Can you provide example data the would result in your above expected output? Thanks

Comment: Assuming `id` is unique, do you want the sum of `click_sum` for all instances of the same date, or do you just want the 'latest' row for a particular date?

Comment: @MattFenwick I want one row per unique updated_at + the SUM(click_sum) of all updated_at rows with that updated_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe I'm assuming too much about the nature of your question (and the table it refers to), but I think this can be done much more simply than the query you've shown.

figuring the latest completed month isn't very hard.

it starts with knowing the first date of this current month -- use this:

```
date_sub(curdate(), interval (extract(day from curdate())-1) day)
```

and to know the first day of that previous month, use this:

```
date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval extract(day from (curdate())-1) day), interval 1 month)
```

so if you want to get the sums for just the days in between -- i.e. the latest completed month, use this:

```
select updated_at, sum(click_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where updated_at >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval extract(day from (curdate())-1) day), interval 1 month)
    and updated_at < date_sub(curdate(), interval (extract(day from curdate())-1) day)
  group by updated_at;
```

figuring the lastest completed week is just as easy. this example will assume a Sunday-Saturday week.

because of the way the ODBC standard defines date numbers, it's easy to find the end (Saturday) of the previous week:

```
date_sub(curdate(), interval dayofweek(curdate()) day)
```

and the beginning (Sunday) of that week is six days before that:

```
date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate())+6) day)
```

so if you want to get the sums for just the days in between -- i.e. the latest completed week, use this:

```
select updated_at, sum(click_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where updated_at >= date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate())+6) day)
    and updated_at <= date_sub(curdate(), interval dayofweek(curdate()) day)
  group by updated_at;
```

and of course figuring based on the latest completed day is super easy.

to get the date of the previous day, use this:

```
date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

so if you want the sums just for yesterday, use this:

```
select updated_at, sum(click_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where updated_at = date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
  group by updated_at;
```

NOTE: I've tested these queries using MySQL 5.1, YMMV.

### ----------

UPDATE: since the date column is a datetime, simply change all references to `updated_at` in my queries to `date(updated_at)` like so:

month case:

```
select date(updated_at), sum(click_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where date(updated_at) >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval extract(day from (curdate())-1) day), interval 1 month)
    and date(updated_at) < date_sub(curdate(), interval (extract(day from curdate())-1) day)
  group by date(updated_at);
```

week case:

```
select date(updated_at), sum(click_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where date(updated_at) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate())+6) day)
    and date(updated_at) <= date_sub(curdate(), interval dayofweek(curdate()) day)
  group by date(updated_at);
```

yesterday case:

```
select date(updated_at), sum(click_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where date(updated_at) = date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
  group by date(updated_at);
```

Comment: I will run those queries today, if our servers will come back (o.O) and give you instant feedback.

Comment: Tested it.
The problem is that you get a single new result row for each unique date.
The dates are in standard date format and include minutes and seconds.
but I want all click_sums of 1 day become one row instead of having a new row for each date differing by a few minutes.

Comment: What is the data type of the date column?

Comment: select updated_at, sum(clicks_sum) from aggregated_clicks
  where updated_at >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval extract(day from (curdate())-1) day), interval 1 month)
    and updated_at < date_sub(curdate(), interval (extract(day from curdate())-1) day)
  group by DAY(updated_at)

Solution is to add "DAY(updated_at)" at the end to have MySQL ignore seconds/minutes/hours and only look at full days

Comment: see edits -- simply change all references to `updated_at` in original queries to `date(updated_at)`